# How to clear the contents of all the attributes of an entity?

Tags: core-data, attributes, xcode10, swift5

I have data recorded in the attributes of a entities in coredata.
I would like to erase the data saved in each attribute of an entity.
Please is there a way to do it and if so, how?

Thank you

Comment: So you do not want to delete the entity object but clear all its values? Why not implement a simple `clear()` function for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the [NSEntityDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsentitydescription) of that object (that's the entity property of the NSManagedObject).
And then you can simply iterate on the names (via the [attributesByName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsentitydescription/1425099-attributesbyname) property) and set all values to nil

```
for (name, attributes) in entity.attributesByName { setValue(nil, forKey: name) }
```

You can do the same for the relationships of that object (via the [relationshipsByName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsentitydescription/1425106-relationshipsbyname) property)

```
for (name, relationship) in entity.relationshipsByName { setValue(nil, forKey: name) }
```

With this methods you can also exclude specific properties  (if there are some you don't want to clear).